# In MYSQL if i am creating a table then i am Getting the error "SQL Error (1022): Can’t write; duplicate key in table companyqualification2texttype"

Tags: mysql

```
CREATE TABLE `CompanyQualification2TextType` 
(
    `CQ2S_ID` VARCHAR(32) NOT NULL,
    `CQ2S_CompanyQualificationID` VARCHAR(32) NOT NULL,
    `CQ2S_TextTypeID` VARCHAR(32) NOT NULL,
    INDEX `CQ2S_TextTypeID` (`CQ2S_TextTypeID`),
    INDEX `CQ2S_CompanyQualificationID` (`CQ2S_CompanyQualificationID`),
    CONSTRAINT `CQ2S_CompanyQualificationID` 
       FOREIGN KEY (`CQ2S_CompanyQualificationID`) 
       REFERENCES `CompanyQualification` (`CQ_ID`),
    CONSTRAINT `CQ2S_TextTypeID` 
       FOREIGN KEY (`CQ2S_TextTypeID`) 
       REFERENCES `texttype` (`TT_ID`)
)
COLLATE='utf8_general_ci'
ENGINE=INNODB;
```

Comment: In MYSQL if i am creating a table then i am Getting the error “SQL Error (1022): Can’t write; duplicate key in table companyqualification2texttype”

Comment: Have you tried looking up the error ? Or googling it? Or reading up on how to create a valid query?

Comment: yes but i didn't get any satisfactory answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that the name of a `foreign key` can not be the same as `another foreign key` in the entire model.

**Imagine this situation**

```
Catalog --> Supplier
Product --> Supplier
```

if the name of the foreign key in table Catalog for supplier is `supplier` and you assigned the same name in product table then the foreign keys names will `collide`.

You need to name them differently..

**For example:**

```
catalog_supplier product_supplier
```